# jQuery-ui Effect/Animation delay to start

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

```
$div.hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000, function() {

 })
```

The code is simple, but the $div has a lot of stuff in it (tables, loads of divs, images, SVG), it takes some time (~0.5s on my PC, ~1s on iPad3) to begin the animation after it's triggered, but once it is it flows pretty well.

Anyone knows any way to improve this? Maybe some way to style my div that improves animation? Right now my div uses:

```
postion: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Comment: Sorry I can't, the application is too big to cut down into a small demo. The actual code of hiding the div is as simple as it was shown in my question.

Comment: why you are setting both top and bottom?this can cause an incorrect behavior.

Comment: try removing right:0 and bottom:0 and setting width and height instead.

Comment: If I remember correctly the animation was not working properly with fixed width/height. I will try to change that though.

Comment: try setting display:table to your div.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
{position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
min-width:100px;
min-height:100px;
}
```

Comment: You know this seems to have improved it considerably. Care to explain why?

Comment: The slide animation likely has far fewer numbers to crunch when it needs to only consider top and left, and using minimum dimensions givs the $div a little more freedom.